# How to make a moving GameObject push a CharacterController smoothly?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I have a GameObject called **Player** with a CharacterController component attached that has the following settings.

[image]

**Player** also has a script called `PlayerController` attached. 
Gravity is applied to the CharacterController through the following function, which is called in `Update()`.

```
private void ApplyGravity()
{
    if (!characterController.isGrounded)
    {
        moveDirection.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;
    }
}
```

The **Player** has a child GameObject called **PlayerModel** which just has a default CapsuleCollider attached.

The `PlayerController` has an additional function called `MoveAround()`, which is also called in `Update()`; incase this is related to the issue.

```
public void MoveAround()
{
    Vector2 moveInput = playerInputActions.Player.Move.ReadValue<Vector2>();

    currentInput = new Vector2(moveInput.y, moveInput.x);

    float moveDirectionY = moveDirection.y;

    float speed = isSprinting ? sprintSpeed : walkSpeed;

    moveDirection = (transform.forward * currentInput.x + transform.right * currentInput.y) + boatController.boatRigidbody.velocity;

    moveDirection.y = moveDirectionY;

    moveDirection.Normalize();

    moveDirection *= speed;
}
```

I have a GameObject called **Boat**, which has a default BoxCollider, Rigidbody and `BoatController` script attached;
the Rigidbody has the following settings.

[image]

The **Boat** is floating on water, therefore moving up and down. 
 The **Player** is resting on the surface of the **Boat**. 
When the **Boat** floats up, the **Player** is pushed upwards with it. When it floats back down, the `ApplyGravity()` function is called, bringing the **Player** back down with it.

The Scene setup looks like this.
[image]

> The problem is this process is not smooth. 
>  The
> **Player** jitters at the collision point when being pushed up, and when falling back down.

I have attempted trying to snap the **Player** position to the surface of the **Boat**, however this causes the same issue. 
Building on from that, I have also tried using the combination of `Physics.Raycast()` and `Vector3.Lerp()` to grab the surface position and smoothly move the **Player** to that position respectively; this caused some strange bugs (but I could've implemented it incorrectly).

Any advice on how to solve this is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

That is normal, since you don't take into account the frame evolution. Usually to smoothen according to frames, the best solution is to multiply by `UnityEngine.Time.deltaTime`. Since this is a physics function, your best bet would rather be using `UnityEngine.Time.fixedDeltaTime`, but that should be called to a relative `FixedUpdate()` instead of `Update()` event.

Try:

`moveDirection *= speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime;`

But make sure your stacktrace is initiated from `FixedUpdate()`. This is the preferred version of the frame update events when it comes to physics. yes, you can also use `Update()`, but the precision is not the same.

Comment: This seems to still result in the same jittering. I will mention that I am moving the CharacterController using `characterController.Move(moveDirection * Time.fixedDeltaTime);`  in `FixedUpdate()`, directly after the `MoveAround()` function is called. I changed to `Time.fixedDeltaTime` there rather than within the `MoveAround()` function - hopefully that is still correct?

Comment: Alright. Let's take this from a different angle :) How about you post the relevant calls, including event calls so that we see all that you "use". Else, it's going to be a hell difficult.